# Playing cards Unicode printing in C++

Tags: c++, unicode, printf

According to [this wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_cards_in_Unicode), the play cards have Unicode of form U+1f0a1.
I wanted to create an array in c++ to sore the 52 standard playing cards but I notice this Unicode is longer that 2 bytes.

So my simple example below does not work, how do I store a Unicode character that is longer than 2 bytes?

```
wchar_t t = '\u1f0a1';
printf("%lc",t);
```

The above code truncates `t` to `\u1f0a`

Comment: to print wide character strings use [wprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wprintf/)

Comment: that is part of the problem... as wchar only stores 2 bytes i am dealing with longer unicode chars

Comment: For characters that are longer than 2 bytes you could use `char32_t`, but looks like it is hard to print such characters in a console ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15857922/3366592))

Comment: @SiddharthChabra Use `std::wstring` instead of `wchar_t`. On platforms where `wchar_t` is 2 bytes (Windows), encode the `std::wstring` using UTF-16, eg: `std::wstring t = L"\uD83C\uDCA1";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do I store a longer that 2 byte unicode character?

you can use `char32_t` with prefix `U`, but there's no way to print it to console.  Besides, you don't need `char32_t` at all, utf-16 is enough to encode that character. `wchar_t t = L'\u2660'`, you need the prefix `L` to specify it's a wide char.

---

If you are using Windows with Visual C++ compiler, I recommend a way:

1. Save your source file with utf-8 encoding
2. set compile parameter `/utf-8`, reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/source-charset-set-source-character-set).
3. use a console supports utf-8 encoded like **Git Bash** to see the result.

[image]

Comment: Most of this is wrong. There is a way to output UTF-16 in the console, git bash has nothing to do with anything, and mainly, ♠ !=  .

Comment: @n.m. OK now I change it to a "recommend way". :D

Comment: "Use git bash" is hardly a recommended way as it requires installing third party software.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows wchar_t stores a UTF-16 code-unit, you have to store your string as UTF-16 (using a string-literal with [prefix](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)) This doesn't help you either since the windows console can only output characters up to 0xFFFF. See this:

[How to use unicode characters in Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/how-to-use-unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line)

Comment: Various console replacements can deal with full range of Unicode characters (I'm using ConEmu and it displays the character in question with no problem whatsoever).